why x11 xserver drawline is faster than directly write buffer?
x11 code
//use x11 api
for (int i = (xrectw >> 1) + cc; i < CANVAS_WIDTH; i += xrectw)
{
    for (int j = (yrectw >> 1) + cc; j < CANVAS_HEIGHT; j += yrectw)
    {
        XDrawLine(sdd->display, sdd->pixmap, sdd->gc, i - 17, j - 13, i + 17, j + 13);
        
        XDrawLine(sdd->display, sdd->pixmap, sdd->gc, i + 17, j - 13, i - 17, j + 13);
    }
}

//directly write buffer
void draw_line(uint32_t *canvas, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, uint32_t c)
{
    // Bresenham's algorithm for drawing straight lines
    int dx = abs(x1 - x0);
    int dy = abs(y1 - y0);
    int sx = (x0 < x1) ? 1 : -1;
    int sy = (y0 < y1) ? 1 : -1;
    int err = dx - dy;

    int width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    int height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;

    uint32_t (*arrayPtr)[CANVAS_HEIGHT] = (uint32_t(*)[CANVAS_HEIGHT])canvas;

    while (x0 != x1 && y0 != y1)
    {
        if (x0 >= 0 && y0 >= 0 && x0 < width && y0 < height)
            arrayPtr[y0][x0] = c;

        int e2 = (err << 1);
        if (e2 > -dy) { err -= dy; x0 += sx; }
        if (e2 < dx) { err += dx; y0 += sy; }
    }
}


_apixmap = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint32_t) * CANVAS_WIDTH * CANVAS_HEIGHT);
memset(_apixmap, 1, sizeof(uint32_t) * CANVAS_WIDTH * CANVAS_HEIGHT);
for (int i = (xrectw >> 1) + cc; i < CANVAS_WIDTH; i += xrectw)
{
    for (int j = (yrectw >> 1) + cc; j < CANVAS_HEIGHT; j += yrectw)
    {
        draw_line_simd(_apixmap, i - 17, j - 13, i + 17, j + 13, c1);
        draw_line_simd(_apixmap, i + 17, j - 13, i - 17, j + 13, c1);
    }
}

both CANVAS_WIDTH and CANVAS_HEIGHT value is 2048
when a draw 208080 lines
x11 only cost 135ms
but directly write the buffer cost 330ms
directly write the buffer have no socket i/o cost, how did x11 do it more faster than it

use it in a pc that have no GPU, it also get this result
it is only use one CPU core, so not multi-thread work
i run the code in more than 3 PCs and VMs, all do same result
i'd use -O2 -O3 -Ofast the compile my code, all use same time


Caching and optimizations. The one you wrote uses neither.

X11 is a client-server architecture. You are measuring your client sending a drawing request to the server, not any actual drawing time.

for "X11 is a client-server architecture. You are measuring your client sending a drawing request to the server, not any actual drawing time. " not correct. i'd call get pc for x11 pixmap code after x11 draw code. the pic is get success. if i draw 10billion lines, x11 draw and copy img times more than draw lines in buffer

if a catch opt, why use buffer have no catch opt?
